# Terraform: " Error creating Firewall: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.firewalls.create' "

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, packer

I´m stuck on this script to deploy an image in GCP with Terraform. The idea is launching a V instance and have opened the ports 443 and 80 for http requests, when i writte "Terraform validate" it is shown as correct:

```
provider "google" {
  project     = "terraform-packer-xxxxxx"
  region      = "us-central1"
  zone        = "us-central1-a"
  credentials = "C:/.../path"
}


data "google_compute_image" "test" {
  name = "packer-08022021-1"
}


resource "google_compute_instance" "myVM" {
  name         = "test"
  machine_type = "e2-micro"
  zone         = "us-central1-a"
  tags = [ "http-server" ]
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = data.google_compute_image.test.self_link
    }
  }
  network_interface {
    # A default network is created for all GCP projects
    network = "default"
    access_config {
    }
  }
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "allow-http" {
  name    = "http-firewall"
  network = "default"

  allow {
    protocol = "all"
    ports    = ["80"]
  }

    allow {
    protocol = "all"
    ports    = ["443"]
  }

    allow {
    protocol = "all"
    ports    = ["22"]
  }

  source_tags = ["http-server"]
}

# resource "google_compute_network" "default" {
#   name = "test-network"
# }

output "ip" {
 value = google_compute_instance.myVM.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip
}
```

But when i writte "Terraform apply" this error apears:

```
Error: Error creating Firewall: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.firewalls.create' permission for 'projects/terraform-packer-303806/global/firewalls/http-firewall'
More details:
Reason: forbidden, Message: Required 'compute.firewalls.create' permission for 'projects/terraform-packer-303806/global/firewalls/http-firewall'
Reason: forbidden, Message: Required 'compute.networks.updatePolicy' permission for 'projects/terraform-packer-303806/global/networks/default'
```

I have doublechecked for the permissions in my service account and i have the following:
Admin of compute instances,
User of service acount,
Networking admin,
Firewall admin.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Are you sure that the service account is authorized on the correct project?

Comment: Are you sure the credentials you're using belongs to the Service Account?

Comment: yes, if i try only to launching the vm instance without the firewall it works perfectly. Last night i could resolve this issue giving the "owner" permission, but i´m sure this is not the best practice ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message provided it seems the Service Account doesn't have the `compute.firewalls.create` permissions assigned. This permission is required in order to create firewall rules, as can be seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls/insert#iam-permissions).

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam) you will find a list of roles which have the permission by searching for `compute.firewalls.`. If none of the roles with the permissions suit your needs you can create custom roles following the steps in the official [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles).

Comment: Thanks @Dylan, that link helped me to fix the issue, seems like it is present is `Compute Security Admin` Role !!!